# PHP/MySQL: Single query vs Multiple calls

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-5.7

Given my situation, what would be a more elegant solution? Here's the query:

```
SELECT id, forum, des, num_topics, num_posts, last_post,
        (SELECT topic_id FROM posts WHERE id = last_post) AS topic_id,
        (SELECT author_id FROM posts WHERE id = last_post) AS author_id,
        (SELECT topic FROM topics WHERE id = (SELECT topic_id FROM posts WHERE id = last_post)) AS topic,
        (SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = (SELECT author_id FROM posts WHERE id = last_post)) AS username
FROM
    (SELECT 
        forums.id, forums.forum, forums.cat_id, forums.des,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM topics WHERE forum_id = forums.id) AS num_topics, 
        COUNT(posts.id) FROM posts AS num_posts,
        MAX(posts.id) AS last_post
    FROM forums
        LEFT JOIN topics ON topics.forum_id = forums.id
        LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.topic_id = topics.id
        GROUP BY forums.id) AS t1
```

It basically selects forum name, description, number of topics and posts per each forum and last active thread derived from the last post id in a specific forum. Everything works, except it looks ugly, particularly the topmost batch of nested SELECTs which seems rather superfluous but I don't see any way to use JOINs there unless I mimicked another table (t2), which I don't really know how to do nor if it's even possible at this point. So I was wondering, is it really more efficient than using a separate SQL call to get the last active thread data? Like this:

```
SELECT topics.topic_id, topics.topic, posts.author_id, users.username 
FROM posts
JOIN topics ON topics.id = posts.topic_id
JOIN users ON users.id = posts.author_id
WHERE posts.id = $last_post
```

As you can see the link here is $last_post which I obtain from the query above and splitting it apart seems more elegant to me than a bunch of nested SELECTs in a single query. But if there is any way to integrate the latter query in the former somehow let me know, please.

Comment: MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8?

Comment: Whether a piece of code is more elegant than another one is in the eye of the beholder. The question is: which one performs better. Sql statements issued in a loop from application code rarely perform better than a complex query, but you should measure both solutions.

Comment: MySQL 5.7.9. Well, performance was implicit. How do I measure it though?

Comment: `t1` appears to have a logical error.  `num_posts` is per topic, not per forum?  This means that each forum can get multiple results from that sub-query; one per topic. 
 As written the engine will return one arbitrary result, so you're getting the number of posts for a pseudo-random topic in that forum?  It appears that you should `SUM()` over that sub-query.

Comment: That's correct, just a clumsy mistake on my part. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Often a large overhead is the network/database connection.  Executing a single query avoids the overheads of executing two queries.

I'd write it as follows, aggregating as I go, then left joining on to the result to pick up the 'latest' posts' details.

Do note, however, that the `MAX(id)` isn't always guaranteed to be the latest row.  transaction and manual interventions can mess with that.  As you're not talking about financial consequences, however, I'd expect it's close enough.

```
SELECT
  forums.*,
  topics.num_topics,
  topics.num_posts,
  latest_post.topic_id    AS latest_post_topic_id,
  post_topic.topic        AS latest_post_topic,
  latest_post.author_id   AS latest_post_author_id,
  post_user.username      AS latest_post_author_username 
FROM
  forums
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    topics.forum_id,
    COUNT(id)              AS num_topics,
    SUM(posts.num_posts)   AS num_posts,
    MAX(posts.max_post_id) AS max_post_id
  FROM
    topics
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      topic_id,
      COUNT(*)   AS num_posts,
      MAX(id)    AS max_post_id
    FROM
      posts
    GROUP BY
      topic_id
  )
    AS posts
      ON posts.topic_id = topics.id
  GROUP BY
    topics.forum_id
)
  AS topics
    ON topics.forum_id = forums.id
LEFT JOIN
  posts  AS latest_post
    ON latest_post.id = topics.max_post_id
LEFT JOIN
  topics  AS post_topic
    ON post_topic.id  = latest_post.topic_id
LEFT JOIN
  users   AS post_user
    ON post_user.id   = latest_post.author_id
```

***EDIT:***

You said in a comment that you don't know what this thing does.

So, break it down, starting from the inner most query...

```
  (
    SELECT
      topic_id,
      COUNT(*)   AS num_posts,
      MAX(id)    AS max_post_id
    FROM
      posts
    GROUP BY
      topic_id
  )
    AS posts

  -- This takes all posts and aggregates to one row per topic
  ---> counts how many posts there are in the topic
  ---> finds the 'newest' post id from that topic
```

Then...

```
(
  SELECT
    topics.forum_id,
    COUNT(id)              AS num_topics,
    SUM(posts.num_posts)   AS num_posts,
    MAX(posts.max_post_id) AS max_post_id
  FROM
    topics
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    <sub-query from above>
  )
    AS posts
      ON posts.topic_id = topics.id
  GROUP BY
    topics.forum_id
)
  AS topics

-- This takes all the topics and aggregates them to one row per forum
---> counts the number of topics in the forum
---> sums the number of posts per topic to the number of posts in the forum
---> finds the 'newest' post id across all the topics' newest posts
```

At this point there is one row per forum, so no more aggregation is required...

```
  forums
LEFT JOIN
(
  <sub-query from above>
)
  AS topics
    ON topics.forum_id = forums.id
LEFT JOIN
  posts  AS latest_post
    ON latest_post.id = topics.max_post_id
LEFT JOIN
  topics  AS post_topic
    ON post_topic.id  = latest_post.topic_id
LEFT JOIN
  users   AS post_user
    ON post_user.id   = latest_post.author_id

--> Take all forums
--> LEFT JOIN the summary stats from the sub-query
--> LEFT JOIN the post, topic and user details for the newest post (as found from the sub-query)
```

Comment: Thank you. So far I failed to adapt it though, because: **#1054 - Unknown column 'topics.max_post_id' in 'on clause'**. I don't know how to fix it because I don't really understand what this whole thing does. This is why I don't like complex queries like that, they are hard to understand and debug. I do have another question, though. Why is it SUM() and not COUNT()? I corrected my initial post with COUNT(posts.id) FROM posts AS num_posts, which does the job just fine?

Comment: There was a typo.  the line `MAX(posts.max_post_id) AS max_post` should have `_id` at the end *(now changed in the answer)*.

Comment: `SUM(num_posts)` adds the values up.  `COUNT(num_posts)` would count how many of the values are not null.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to use aggregation in the future.